# Use JSP code of one Component which is a Component link in another Component where we need to render it in DXA 1.5 Java

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

Component1 - uses **model1** - `component1.jsp`

Component2 - uses **model2** - `component2.jsp`

Component1 --> Component link --> Component2

```
<jsp:include page="component2.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

I want to reuse the JSP code from `component2.jsp` in my `component1.jsp`.

Is there a way to get use the `component2.jsp` which uses a different model?

I know that if both of them have same models it will work.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a bit more detail, like some of the source of `model1` for example, which shows the Component Link field?

Answer (score 1):

Each Tridion Component is has a Cchema and the DXA webapp model is created using the Field definitions in Schema.

So, as long as Component1 and Component2 have same Schema, they both have the same model or at least type castable

Comment: They are separate schema s

Comment: If you have different Schemas, you can map them to the same View Model type or to different View Model types which have a common base class.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `<dxa:entity entity="${component2}"/>` not sure if it will work in your setup though.